# Product: ASUS Update Helper — Error 1316. The specified account already exists

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer, error-logging

I've been looking for an answer all over the net for the last 12 hours and most answers always seem to suggest the same things; using a registry cleanup such as CCleaner and using the microsoft diagnostics cab.

I've tried these and cannot figure out 1) what's triggering the error and 2) how to prevent it.

As the title says, event viewer is throwing an error; MsiInstaller 11316 with the details that Product: ASUS Update Helper -- Error 1316. The specified account already exists.

However, I'm not trying to install/uninstall anything, and I can't seem to find what the ASUS Update Helper is, nor is there anything installed by that name. I've uninstalled everything with the name ASUS from the apps tab and there are no programs in the start menu.

There are, however, entries in services:

[Services Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye2KV.png)

My motherboard is an ASUS Prime Z370-A II so it could be related but I would still like to fix whatever the cause is.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would start with listing the local users, group and the computer name.  Can you detail the output of the following commands in an administrative command prompt: `net user` `net localgroup` and `hostname`, feel free to alter any personal names but keep any alterations consistent across all 3 outputs.  Also you have a screenshot of the service names, but what account do they run as?  It seems to me the installer probably tries to create a local account in order to run a service or maybe a scheduled task as.  If the account already exists, then you get the above message.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!


The services are all set to run as Local System, I've since set them to start manually and stopped them. As of yet I'm yet to see another instance of the error in the event viewer, although I'm not sure disabling the services is the best option in the long run as I assume they're there for a reason?


https://imgur.com/a/FPWBB25


There's the cmd output

Comment: I don't see any accounts in your output that would conflict with what I might expect to be created with that software.  It might help if I had the MSI file of the installer to open it up in Orca to see what's going on. I can't really find the software myself.  If you could find the installer of the software and link it I'd have a look.

Comment: That's part of the issue, I have no idea what software was triggering the install, or from where. I couldn't find any msi files relating to ASUS. I downloaded the drivers for my motherboard from the Asus website, none of which appear in the form of msi files. So far I've experienced no issues and no event logged items since disabling the services so I'm not sure what else to do about it so far. Thank you for your assistance though!